# IE11 BHO: Replacing ActiveX objects in HTML document

Tags: html, c++, internet-explorer, activex, bho

I'm developing a BHO, currently in IE11, that  replaces specific ActiveX objects in document, by searching for the `<object>` tag with a determined CLSID.

I looked into handling the `OnDocumentComplete` event, searching for all the "object" tags using standard HTML interfaces, and I successfully replaced them; I checked in DOM Explorer and the new CLSIDs are there.

Now, there is an important drawback on this approach that renders it not functional. When I receive the OnDocumentComplete event the browser has already instantiated the DLLs specified by the CLSIDs on the document turning the new CLSIDs that I've replaced completely useless.

This is I think due to the ActiveX loading occurring immediately after loading document (that is, ReadyState = 2), while I receive the OnDocumentComplete event with ReadyState=4.

Does anyone knows if this kind of "ActiveX object replacement"  is achievable using standard IE interfaces? I'm using C++.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you, you're trying to replace one specific ActiveX control with another specific ActiveX control, based on ClSID?  If that's correct, have you considered using the [Phoenix bit](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2008/02/07/the-kill_2d00_bit-faq_3a00_-post-2-of-3.aspx)?

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Comment: Thank you very much Lance, very interesting information. However,to be more precise, I need to do it per HTML document (it's URL-selective) not "globally".

Comment: I don't know of any services that would allow you to intercept a document on the fly, though given the number of available interfaces (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206442(v=vs.85).aspx) , it makes sense that one might exist.  Given, though, the lack of recent attention to the C++ side of the platform, it seems reasonable to think that things are moving away from that direction.  Perhaps modifying the source to use the alternate CLSID's using Powershell or other grep-like utilities?  I suppose a proxy intercept/rewrite might also work, but that's beyond my meager skills.